# gradient of projection operator in projected gradient descent

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, constraints

Sometimes to solve a constrained optimization problem, projected gradient descent algorithm is used. 
Since the projection to a constraint set is some function, one might think it is needed to compute the gradient of this projection function via chain rule/backprop once applying the projection. This is not right, but can someone give some intuition or rigorous reasoning why?

Comment: Why do you believe it would be necessary to compute the gradient _after_ the projection has been applied? The work has already been done at that point. This is in contrast to standard gradient descent—because you're using the gradient to figure out where to go next.

Comment: I just was not clear how I should think about it to see the difference between the two case well.

Comment: Basically, projected gradient alternates between reducing the objective function, with no concern about the constraints, with a “jump” back to constraint satisfaction.